# Xcode can not jump to xib from h or m file

Tags: xcode, outlet

I click this black icon in red box mark area at the picture below,
its will show a pop window natural:

[image]

Now in Xcode7.1. it is only mark breakpoint when I click it.
I have try right click,option click, cmd click and so on.

[image]

Comment: i solve it,please close this question.

Comment: then please add an answer

Comment: A plug cause this,i forgot its name,but that plug use to auto fold code.I uninstall it and Xcode work normal again.